# Assign One User to Multiple Projects and/or Assign Multiple Users to One Project

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to write an app that will let me assign one user to multiple projects and also allow me to assign multiple users to one project. I know there are already some 3rd party apps that accomplish this, but because I believe it is a core feature of BIM360 I would like to have an option to handle this routine task internally without relying on 3rd party solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to assign multiple users to one project but not assign multiple projects to a specific user. That is basically how BIM360 works.

You can add up to 50 users per call.

You can specify the following details about the user:

1. The user’s access level for the project (admin or user).
2. The company the user is assigned to for the project.
3. The industry roles assigned to the user for the project.
4. The user’s email address.

To assign multiple users to a project, check out this [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/)

Comment: Thanks @Arrotech! I actually did find an app that allows me to add multiple users to a project (Shout-out to the 360 Admin Tools team!) but one of the interesting bugs is it does not seem to automatically activate the Design Collaboration tools, only Document Management.

Comment: Regarding the issue of assigning multiple projects to a specific user, am I understanding correctly that this is an intentional aspect of BIM360, and therefore there is no way to program an app around that limitation?

Comment: @otj You mean adding a user to multiple projects in a single call? Because it's possible to add multiple users to a project (usually up to 50 users per call) with BIM360.

Comment: @otj You can activate the other services (e.g Design Collaboration) from the BIM360 UI through an account admin. It is not possible to do that from the API. Check out this link https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Administration/files/About-Project-Admin/GUID-62233D06-249B-4D6E-BC05-5303642220A3-html.html

Comment: Thanks @arrotech! Correct, all I am trying to do is add ONE user to Multiple projects in a single call. For example, we hire one or two new architects each week. We have currently more than 100 active projects. My current workflow is to spend several hours adding each of those new architects one-by-one to all 100 of our current projects. As you can see, this is a BIG waste of my time! I hope it is possible to simply add ONE user to multiple projects in a single call using BIM360 or ACC API. I know I can add multiple users to a single project, so why not also the reverse?? Thanks again!!